# Spark Scala - Turning A Column With XML in a Dataframe to Multiple Columns

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe that has two columns, a pk and an xml string. I need to turn the xml string into columns in this data frame.

ex.

```
|pk|xml_string|

|1|<root><EventDate>2019-01-01</EventDate><EventCode>7</EventCode></root>|

|2|<root><EventDate>2019-05-01</EventDate><EventCode>8</EventCode></root>|

|3|<root><EventDate>2019-08-01</EventDate><EventCode>9</EventCode></root>|
```

Need to turn it into:

```
|pk|EventDate|EventCode|

|1|2019-01-01|7|

|2|2019-05-01|8|

|3|2019-08-01|9|
```

```
//working to potentially map it before parsing, but haven't gotten far
%spark

import scala.xml._

val blob = sqlContext.table("inspecRiskBlob")

val blobMap = blob
  .rdd.map(row => (
    row.getString(0),
    row.getString(1))
  ).collectAsMap()
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome to SO. One option would be to transform your XML into JSON using a library like json4s and then use Spark's built-in JSON functions to manipulate your data, but for a simple case like this you can indeed use Scala's XML module to extract the values you need:

```
scala> import scala.xml.XML
import scala.xml.XML

scala> val in = Seq(("1", "<xml><date>2019-01-01</date><eventId>11</eventId></xml>"), ("2", "<xml><date>2019-01-02</date><eventId>22</eventId></xml>")).toDS
in: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(String, String)] = [_1: string, _2: string]

scala> val extracted = in.map{
     | case (id : String, xml : String) => 
     | val x = XML.loadString(xml)
     | (id, (x \ "date").text, (x \ "eventId").text)
     | }.toDF("pk", "date", "event")
extracted: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [pk: string, date: string ... 1 more field]

scala> extracted.show(false)
+---+----------+-----+
|pk |date      |event|
+---+----------+-----+
|1  |2019-01-01|11   |
|2  |2019-01-02|22   |
+---+----------+-----+
```